# Load html without refresh

Tags: ajax, django, html, mongodb, backbone.js

Im unsure of how to approach this, should I have the html to be loaded hidden or load it from somewhere? I want to load a form in one page, and dynamic content on other pages.

The form can be saved to mongo db, and when the page loads should load the data into that form from mongo db.

Where does the html live for all the pages? I want to have a clean html5 document with lets say a content div. all content goes into that block.

Server running Django
Im want to use backbone.js for the app

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The initial page should include the basic layout of the application (header, content, sidebar, different placeholder for your views, etc.)

Then you load the application (usually with a controller) and render the different view that will replace the placeholders you had in your layout.

To render the views, I suggest to use a templating engine. With backbone.js there is already underscore.js on the page, so you can use the templating engine included (http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template). You then have to load the template on the page. The easiest way is to create include a script element on the page with your template inside:

```
<script type="text/template" name="template1">
your template here...
</script>
```

And you can load it using this:

```
var template = _.template( jQuery("script[name=template1]").text() )
```

and execute with your data

```
var html = template(model)
```

You build your page with different backbone views using different template.

I hope that help!